# undirected graph incidence matrix implementation

Tags: c++, vector, graph, graph-algorithm

Here I wrote a little program to represent graph using [incidence matrix](https://www.eeeguide.com/define-incidence-matrix/), with use of vector of vector to incorporate dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
void print_graph(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &adj);
void addEdge(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& adj, int u, int v);

int main()
{
// Initialise array to hold adjacency matrix, vec<>s is already dynamic
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(3);
    addEdge(adj,0,1);     // edge from node 0 to node 1
    addEdge(adj,0,2);
    addEdge(adj,1,2);
    print_graph(adj);
  //  return 0;
}

void print_graph(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& adj)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++ )
    {
        for(std::size_t j = 0 ; j < adj[i].size(); j++ )
        {
            std::cout << adj[i][j]<< "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void addEdge(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& adj, int u , int v)
{
    adj[u][v]=1;
    adj[v][u]=1;
}
```

Program crashed...everyone segmentation fault comes I am lost even debugger's on.
I pasted that to compiler explorer, feel that the `std::__throw_bad_cast()@plt` indicates a bug but i duno how to fix it...
Ideas anyone?

Comment: Hint -- how do you add a value to a vector?  You don't use `[ ]` for that.

Comment: i guess you mean `adj.push_back(value)` or `adj.resize()`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I cannot figure out how you think `[ ]` might be left out, suppose my matrix initialized in my original way `std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(3)`  I tried replaced the last two lines of my code as `adj[u].push_back(v)`. The result was nonsense. Could you suggest your way if I want to keep my original way of initialization?

Comment: The inner vector will not magically add values to it by using `[ ]` -- it still is a vector.  You add items to a vector by either 1) constructing it with the size given in the constructor, 2) calling `push_back`,  3) calling `insert`, 4) calling `emplace_back`, 5) calling `resize`.  Choose the one you will use.  All `[ ]` does is *access* elements -- it does not add elements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Here I just to replace some of those 0s with 1s, whenever there is a connection between two nodes. So what I want is to access particular elements and refill that to 1s. If I keep my original way of initializing `adj` but replace my last two lines with `adj[u].resize(3,1)` and `adj[v].resize(3,1)`. The whole rows and columns become 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(3);
```

defines a vector of 3 empty vectors. Try that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > adj(3, std::vector<int>(3));
```

Comment: I read somewhere on the internet...I thought if for square matrix `adj(3)` suffice. Yesterday I did the ajacency matrix and I need just that...confused...
I ticked your answer anyway:)